# Clicking a menu link to bring up sign up box via js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have set up a pop up sign up box to show on first site arrival that is loaded using a .js file called inside the `<head>` tag and this all works fine.

How can i get it to re-show if a menu link is clicked?

Obviously when i link it like this below it will open the file itself containing the codes.

```
<a href="/popup.js">Mailing List</a>
```

So how do i get it to carry out the function that's in `popup.js` when the above link is clicked?

**Edit: I was able to get the pop up to show by using the below thank you all who contributed.**

```
<a href="" onclick="popup();">Mailing List</a>
```

**Now to complete what i'm trying to achieve is to ignore/disable the cookie being set that stops the popup from showing the next time the link is clicked.**

```
function AlreadyBeenNewsletter()
```

**and**

```
function SetNewsletterCookie()
```

[Link to the actual js file](http://hea6664.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/popup.js)

Comment: Not sure we can help you without knowing what is in the popup.js file.

Comment: just add a reference to the function you need using `addEventListener`

Comment: @GeorgettePincin popup.js file was linked in the original post see "Link to the actual js file"

Answer (score 1):

If the JS is already included, you could use the `onclick` attribute. It will run JS code when a link is clicked.

```
<a href="#" onclick="theFunction();"> Mailing List</a>
```

For the second part of your question, I would create two functions. One that shows the popup without checking if the cookie is set, and another (you already have it) that checks the cookie.

Function that shows popup without checking:

```
function showPopup(){
   var id;
   id = "popupSignup";
   if (jq(".popupWindow").length) {
      jq(".popupWindow").prop("id", id); 
   } else {
      jq("#aspnetForm").after('<div id="popupSignup" class="popupWindow"><a class="popupClose" href="javascript:;"></a><div class="popupDetails"></div></div><div class="backgroundPopup"></div>');

   }
   jq("#" + id + " .popupDetails").html('<iframe class="popupiframe" src="/user/files/newsletter.html"></iframe>');
   InitialisePopup(id, 99, false, true);
   ShowPopup();
   CenterPopup();
}
```

Function that you already have `popup()`

```
jq(function popup() {
   if (!AlreadyBeenNewsletter()) {
      SetNewsletterCookie();
      showPopup();
   }
});
```

Then you can do the following for your link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showPopup();">Mailing List</a>
```

By separating the two functions apart like this you are free to show the popup without preventing it from showing again.

Comment: could you shed more light on this please? Thanks

Comment: From what I can tell, looking at your code, you should put `InitialisePopup('popupSignup, 99, false, true);ShowPopup();CenterPopup();` in the `onclick`. The onclick attribute basically runs any javascript when the item is clicked. So if you put `alert('test');` in the onclick, you would get an alert when you clicked that link. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes it did thank you i was able to follow your suggestion and get the pop up to show, could you please revisit my original post above to see the next step i'm trying to achieve. Thanks